# Does Apple still monitor or track after having a customer support screen sharing service with ara.apple.com?

Tags: apple

Is having screen sharing service with ara.apple.com safe?

I had screensharing service with ara.apple.com(https://ara-prn.apple.com/) which is official apple website for apple products support. And they wanted me to install an app after entering session key and they said the app will self-destruct once support session ended.

Would there be a possibility that Apple can still track and monitor that computer even after the support session ended and even if they claim that installment of the app for screen sharing self-destruct?

Comment: Apple can do that before, during, and after your visit; they control the updates.

Comment: @dandavis I had this screen sharing service on the phone call. Would this make any different from visiting?

Answer (score 0):

There's always possibility...

Nevertheless, why would they continue tracking and monitoring you using this tools since they can put any backdoor they want as editor of the operating system ? It would be far easier to do this directly on the OS shipped with your device.

Moreover, such a monitoring would probably be discovered and lead to a scandal...

Comment: While I agree with your general conclusion, I'm not quite sure that your reasoning is correct on all points.  If you don't think they would do this because it would probably be discovered and lead to scandal, then you can't suggest that they wouldn't do it because they could just build it in the OS - that would also probably be discovered and lead to scandal.  Therefore your argument is that they (probably) won't do this because of the risk of being caught, and their ability to build a backdoor in the OS is a red herring.